# Adapt dest folder to ** globbing pattern

Tags: gruntjs, grunt-contrib-copy

I'm working with grunt-contrib-copy. I have this file tree:

```
`-- src
    `-- model
        |-- a4
        |   `-- public
        |       |-- css
        |       |-- img
        |       `-- js
        |-- posters
        |   `-- public
        |       |-- css
        |       |-- img
        |       `-- js
        `-- prints
            `-- public
                |-- css
                |-- img
                `-- js
```

I would like to copy the files in
`src/model/**/public/img` to `dist/images/{1}/` where `{1}` is the folder name (a4, posters, prints... dynamic folders that are bound to change too), so:

`src/model/a4/public/img/file.png -> dist/images/a4/file.png`

Is there a way to specify that with grunt-contrib-copy (maybe the rename function?) or do I have to iterate manually over the files?

Right now this is what I have:

```
grunt.registerTask 'images-generate', ->
gruntCopyFiles.images = {
  expand: true,
  cwd: './src/model/',
  src: ["**/public/img/*.png", "**/public/img/*.jpg"],
  dest: "./dist/images/"
}
```

But this copies `src/model/a4/public/img/file.png` to `dist/images/a4/public/img/file.png` which is not what I want.

Any suggestion? Thanks!

Comment: Just realized I'm probably using grunt.file.expandMapping and not grunt-contrib-copy. Maintaining someone else's project is fun.

Comment: do you still have that issue than?

Comment: Yep! Just wanted to be clear about the tech. Right now I'm using the rename function, but if there is a better/built-in/shorter way, I'll take it. I doubt it tho!

Comment: alright, great. could you add your current attempt with `rename` to the question, to make it clearer for readers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to specify that with `grunt-contrib-copy` (maybe the rename function?) or do I have to iterate manually over the files?

Utilizing the `rename` function is the way to achieve this. Glob patterns alone cannot meet your requirement, nor can the `flatten` option.

Something like the following also copies any subfolders which ***may*** potentially reside inside the source `img` folders:

```js
gruntCopyFiles.images = {
    expand: true,
    cwd: 'src/model',
    dest: 'dist/images',
    src: '**/public/img/**/*.{png,jpg,gif}',
    rename: function(dest, src) {
        var items = src.split('/'),
            baseIndex = items.indexOf('img') + 1,
            subPath = items.slice(baseIndex, items.length).join('/');

        return [dest, items[0], subPath].join('/');
    }
}
```

**Example:**

`src/model/a4/public/img/file.png` --> `dist/images/a4/file.png`

`src/model/a4/public/img/`**`quux`**`/file.jpg` --> `dist/images/a4/`**`quux`**`/file.jpg`

Comment: I ended up doing something similar, but great point in including potential subfolders :) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you can use `flatten` to get stripped-down destination paths:

```
gruntCopyFiles.images = {
  flatten: true,
  expand: true,
  cwd: './src/model/',
  src: ["**/public/img/*.png", "**/public/img/*.jpg"],
  dest: "./dist/images/"
}
```

From [the docs](https://gruntjs.com/configuring-tasks#building-the-files-object-dynamically):

> - `flatten` Remove all path parts from generated dest paths.